# Why NetBean IDE 7.3.1 and 8.0 always stop working?

Tags: netbeans-7, netbeans-platform, netbeans6.8

I've always got errors not responding or stop working while I coding on NetbeanIDE 7.3.1 or 8.0.
My computer capacity:

- Ram:4Mb,
- CPU:COI5 2.60GH
- hardesk:1Tb

Do any body have any solution or I have to stop using IDE forever?

Comment: U have to be more specific than that. What r u trying to do and is happening when u do what you do.

Comment: Just stop use IDE forever is ok too muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuch annoying me